# Path to network file

Tags: php, networking, file-copying

My web server is running on one server, and the data fetching is running on another server. My code will try copy a remote file and store it in my local path. The remote location is, for example, /home/testUser/remoteData.xml. I know the server IP address and hostname. How can I construct the path to fill in the remotePath?

```
#remotePath is the path to the file on the network
public function __construct()
{
   $this->localPath="currentData.xml";
   $this->remotePath="a remote path";
}

#this will attempt to make a copy from that network file and store it locally
private function fetchServer()
{
   if (!(file_exists($this->remotePath)) || (time() - filectime($this->remotePath)) >= 1200)
      return false;
   else
   {  $success = copy($this->remotePath, $this->localPath);
      if($success)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you want to copy the data? SSH? Serve the file via HTTP? Mount the remote directory via NFS? There are several options here, but without knowing the configuration of your server, it's impossible to present a complete solution.

Comment: I would like to serve it via HTTP. :(. I am quite new to this aspect so excuse the obscurity :(

Comment: Please supply a method that you are able to connect to remote server. For example SSH, FTP, HTTP, NFS etc.

Comment: For example, I can view the file on the browser following this URL `https://somehostname.com/weather/remoteData.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTTP, you won't be able to check the creation time. If you know that it is a small, manageable file, you can use file_get_contents:

```
 $fl = @file_get_contents( '<stream>' );
 if( !$fl ) return false; // file does not exist remotely
 $ret = @file_put_contents( '<output name>', $fl );// just output it
 return $ret && true; //force it to boolean
```

If it is a bit larger, you can use the cURL and stream syntax, or you can do something similar to what I did above:

```
 $fl = @fopen( '<stream>' );
 if( !$fl ) return false;// file does not exist remotely
 $out = @fopen( '<local file>', 'w');
 if( !$out ) return false;
 while($data = fread($fl)){fwrite($out,$data);}
 fclose($out);
 return true;
```

Of course, all situations you will have to download the file to a local version and then do some form of checksum to see if there is a difference.

### EDIT

---

You just mentioned that timestamp is a requirement but that you also have SSH. If you have SSH, then you might be able to use SFTP (which is something that piggy-backs off of SSH). I have used [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) for several projects and, while not perfect (it is in PHP4 and it does not truly tunnel for SSH), it is a very impressive library nevertheless. Look at the [networking](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html) part of the manual and (if I remember) it will give you more than enough to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you! But then I am required to check for the creation time. If there is no way to do it using HTTP then is there any other way around? I can SSH to the server too. Should I include a timestamp inside the file?

Comment: If you include the timestamp as line 1 of the file, then the first `fread` will yield the timestamp, but I don't know if you want to do that. See my edit for more on SSH.

Comment: The file will be an XML and the timestamp would also be a node in the XML. I think I would have to use xpath for that task. However, is it possible to get the file from https?

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. I will have to create a new node in the XML with the timestamp for time checking purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTTP and PHP allow_url_fopen directive is enabled you can directly use URL for your file. Example:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.yourdomain.dom/virtual/path/to-your-file');
```

`/virtual/path/to-your-file` is relative path to your document root.

If you have a restricted PHP environment that does not allow to open remote files, you can use PHP [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or PHP [streams](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php).

EDIT:

To save the file contents to the local file use the counterpart of file_get_contents(): [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Example:

```
file_put_contents('path/to/the/local-file', $content);
```

Comment: and how to save that file into my local folder? :( I want to make a copy of it though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand your question but if your remote location is

```
http://www.somehost.com/home/testUser/remoteData.xml
```

then this is exactly your path. You have to begin with http:// if you like get the source via HTTP. Use ftp:// if you wish to get it with FTP. This will instruct the copy() function to initiated the appropriate protocol

Edit: About filectime() this is a filesystem function and will not work for HTTP or FTP. If you are the author of the source file you may set some date time information into the header.